# Ext JS Cycle through items of a Ext.form.CheckboxGroup

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a Ext.form.CheckboxGroup with multiple items of Ext.form.Checkbox.

Is it possible to cycle through each item of the Ext.form.CheckboxGroup?

I have tried the following to no avail:

```
for ( var i in Ext.getCmp('product_category_group').items.items) {
    console.log(i.getId());
}
```

Any advice appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me : (*ExtJs 3.2*)

```
Ext.getCmp('product_category_group').items.each(function(i) {
   console.log(i.getId());
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question, or not ?